# SQL concat / + operator behaving strangely?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So basically to explain my situation I have a program where a user can select code numbers, that are alpha numeric.  These codes are stored in my SQL database as datatype char.

When they select all the codes they want, the program then sends a few parameters(the codes being one of them).  The codes are strung together and look something like this:

',01,1,A3' etc. etc. with commas separating the codes.  I have the comma in front, but changing the comma to the back does not change anything.

the @reasonCode variable is the reason codes strung together.

In my where clause I have a statement that is this:

```
(@reasonCode = 'ALL') OR 
((@reasonCode <> 'ALL' AND (charindex(',' +     ro_reason_code, @reasonCode) > 0)))
```

Basically I want to restrict my results to just those that have those specific reason codes the user selected(among other parameters).  I am trying to achieve that by stringing together the codes, and then searching through them using charindex, seperated by commas.

However I am running into an issue.  Here are the results using a few different variations of reason codes:

```
',1' = 625 records (correct number)  
',01' = 1015(correct number)  
',01,1 = 1640(correct number)  
',1,01' = 1015(for whatever reason it isn't picking up the 1 reason codes)
```

That is my issue right there.

When I put the 1 in front of the 01, it doesn't pick up the 1 reason codes.  But if I do it flip-flopped it works fine...

Any ideas as to why this happens?
(I have tried also using the concat function and get the same results, and also tried forcing everything to be char datatype.)

In the end I would like the same result, regardless if it is ,01,1 or ,1,01.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? `+` is concatenation in the latter, but I not the former.

Comment: Sql Server 2014

Comment: Can you create a script that reproduces the problem?   I have a suspicion about the cause, but it relies on a small inaccuracy in your question, which I am loathe to assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because you said you're using the `char` type instead of `varchar`. Try replacing your `charindex` expression with this:

```
charindex(',' + rtrim(ro_reason_code), @reasonCode)
```

When I used a type of `char(2)` in the table and `char(16)` for the `@reasonCode`, I could reproduce your result, and I found that adding the `rtrim` fixed the problem. But unfortunately I can't explain exactly what's going here, why having ',1' at the end of the string should work without the trim whereas having it at the beginning does not. Hopefully someone can provide a more in-depth answer that gets into the "why," but I thought I'd still post this for the time being to get you running.

Reproduction:

```
-- Forgive the "hackish" way of populating this table. I'm assuming sysobjects has >=1015 records.
declare @Code table (ro_reason_code char(2));
insert @Code select top 625 '1' from sysobjects;
insert @Code select top 1015 '01' from sysobjects;

declare @reasonCode char(16); 

set @reasonCode = ',1,01';
select count(1) from @Code where @reasonCode = 'ALL' or charindex(',' + ro_reason_code, @reasonCode) > 0;        -- Result: 1015
select count(1) from @Code where @reasonCode = 'ALL' or charindex(',' + rtrim(ro_reason_code), @reasonCode) > 0; -- Result: 1640

set @reasonCode = ',01,1';
select count(1) from @Code where @reasonCode = 'ALL' or charindex(',' + ro_reason_code, @reasonCode) > 0;        -- Result: 1640
select count(1) from @Code where @reasonCode = 'ALL' or charindex(',' + rtrim(ro_reason_code), @reasonCode) > 0; -- Result: 1640
```

Comment: That could only be true if the OP wasn't entirely accurate in describing the issue.   If `char` is the issue, then the tests with `',1'` should not return the correct results.    However, this is my first thought as well.

Comment: @TabAlleman, I added a bit of exposition. I actually was able to reproduce the issue, so I'm pretty confident in the answer, but I don't understand why it's necessary. Actually I think I'll update again with my reproduction.

Comment: I see, I was assuming OP is using `varchar` for `@ReasonCode` variable, but if he is using `char` then yes, you would be reproducing his results, and this would be the answer.

Comment: You sir, are a life saver!  I am not too sure why the trim is fixing it... but that did it.

Comment: I tried forcing everything as both varChar and char, and that did not work either.  Actually forcing it to varchar didn't work at all.

Comment: @JacobTurley I would have to see your attempt to use varchar to explain why it didn't work.   If done correctly, it would work perfectly.

Comment: That's odd, @JacobTurley. When I change the snippet shown above to use `varchar(2)` and `varchar(16)` for the column and local variable, respectively, I get 1640 from all four `select` statements.

Comment: Testing it now using a simpler query varchar and char didn't change anything.  So I probably just got caught up in the complexity and changed something that affected it otherwise.  Regardless, the desired result can only be achieved with char datatype and trimming.  Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using char, which is a fixed length field, your data is stored padded out to the length of the field. So `'1'` is stored as `'1 '`

```
DECLARE @Code CHAR(2)
SET @Code = '1'

SELECT '''' + @Code + ''''
-- Printes '1 '
```

For that reason, when you add ',' to the value, you now have `',1 '` (notice the trailing whitespace)

```
DECLARE @Code CHAR(2)
SET @Code = '1'

SELECT '''' + ',' + @Code + ''''
-- prints ',1 '
```

Now if you're comparing off another char field, there will also be padded whitespace if the character data is less than the length of the field. So what appers to be `',11,1'` is actually something like `',11,1       '` which does match the pattern of `',1 '`

BUT, when you reverse the order, `',1,11'` becomes `',1,11     '` which does not match the pattern of `',1 '`

### Unrelated

I just want to point out there is a subtle issue with the implementation. By only appending the leading comma, you may get false positives depending on your data. For example, `,2` will match the pattern `,25`.

`,2` does match `1,11,25,A01`

You've gotta append the comma on both sides of each side of the evaluation.

```
CHARINDEX( ',' + RTRIM(ro_reason_code) + ',',
           ',' + RTRIM(@reasonCode)    + ',') > 0
```

So to illustrate the difference it becomes

`,2,` does not match `,1,11,25,A01,`

Comment: +1 for getting the piece I was missing: the behavior observed in the OP only occurs if *both* the table field and the local variable are `char` fields. If I change the local variable to `varchar` and leave the table field at `char`, then the inputs `'01,1'` and `'1,01'` both produce 1015, because there's no longer any padding at the end of the variable contents. Seems obvious now that you point it out. :) Good answer.